# circle link list C

Tags: c, linked-list

i trying build circle link lisrt but i have problem how i found the tail if is it link list

i trying this buy after 2 links i have bugs

```
 Node* ListMakeNode(Node* before, int val)
{
    Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node* tail = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    tail = node;
    if (node) {
        node->value = val;
        node->next = before;
    }
    while (tail->next != NULL && tail->next != node && tail->next != tail)
        tail = tail->next;
    tail->next = node;
    return node;
}
```

Comment: are you using any other method to add the node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the basics for circular linked list you need to have, `front`, `rear` and `temp`

```
typedef struct node
{
   int value;
   struct node *next;
} Node;

Node *front=NULL,*rear=NULL,*temp;
```

To create a node, you need to define the `front` and `rear`

```
Node *newnode;
newnode=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
newnode->value = 12;
newnode->next=NULL;
if(rear==NULL)
front=rear=newnode;
else
{
    rear->next=newnode;
    rear=newnode;
}

rear->next=front;
```

To display all nodes, you need to use `temp` without disturbing the front or rear and you need check until `rear` is reached

```
temp=front;
for(;temp!=rear;temp=temp->next)
    printf("\n%d \t",temp->value);

printf("\n%d \t",temp->value);
```

Full code here https://pastebin.com/sQQAsj6m